# java - ArrayList contains another ArrayList of self-defined object type

Tags: java, sequence, intervals

I am new to Java and search for method to check if an ArrayList contains another ArrayList of self-defined object type, and the order relation must keep the same.

For example:

```
public class IntervalPoint implements Comparable<IntervalPoint>{
    private String label;
    private boolean startend;
}

ArrayList<IntervalPoint> a1;
ArrayList<IntervalPoint> a2;
ArrayList<IntervalPoint> a3;
ArrayList<IntervalPoint> a4;

a1 has elements: (a,1) (b,1) (a,0) (b,0)
a2 has elements: (a,1) (b,1) (c,1) (a,0) (c,0) (b,0)
a3 has elements: (a,1) (b,1) (b,0) (a,0)
a3 has elements: (a,1) (c,1) (a,0) (c,0)

a2.contains(a1) returns true
a3.contains(a1) returns false, since the order relationshops are changed
a3.contains(a1) returns false, since the element is different
```

I've checked containsAll() function but it seems not the correct one for this application.
My idea is to override a sequentially scanning methods, which examine if an element in a1 is contained in ax; if the target is found, restart scanning from that position afterward to find the next element in a1.
But this would be quiet time consuming...

Comment: Have you overridden equals?

Comment: In order for `containsAll()` to work, you must implement the [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to define when two `IntervalPoint` objects are equal. When implementing `equals()`, you should also implement [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), which will allow you to improve the `containsAll()` performance by changing from `ArrayList` to `HashSet`, `LinkedHashSet`, or `TreeSet` (unordered, by insert order, or as defined by `compareTo()` method, respectively).